# Increment by 0.1 for every change in column in R

Tags: r

Using this data frame I would like to increase var2 by 0.1 for each change in var1

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c("a", "a", "1", "0", "b", "b", "b", "c", "1", "1"))
```

in this case the result should be:

```
var1 var2
   a    1
   a    1
   1    1.1
   0    1.2
   b    1.3
   b    1.3
   b    1.3
   c    1.4
   1    1.5
   1    1.5
```

I was able to use the following code to increase var2 by 1 for each change in var1 but I could not manipulate this to increase by 0.1.

```
df$var2 <- c(0,cumsum(as.numeric(with(df,var1[1:(length(var1)-1)] != var1[2:length(var1)]))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
df$var1 <- as.character(df$var1)
df$var2 <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)[with(df, cumsum(c(TRUE, var1[-1]!= var1[-length(var1)])))] + 1
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for the help, I spent too long scratching my head over this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can split this task into smaller tasks, and complete them in order.

1. Create a column which is "lagging" in one row
2. Compare the 2 columns
3. Calculate the cumulative sum, put it in the dataframe

So in code:

`helper = c(df$var1[1],df$var1[1:(nrow(df)-1)])`

`isDifferent = as.integer(df$var1)!=helper` note the casting to int due to R creating the strings as factors

`df$var2=1+cumsum(isDifferent *0.1)`